# How to pass data from flutter -> swift && swift -> flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I'm working on both flutter and swift in order to customize my camera.

My Flutter version
[image: flutter doctor -v]

My XCode version
[image: XCode version]

I've made my camera as below
[image: custom camera screen]

I want to take a picture when button is pressed. How can I complete this?

Here is my code

.dart file

```dart
class IOSCompositionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const IOSCompositionWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<IOSCompositionWidget> createState() => _IOSCompositionWidgetState();
}

class _IOSCompositionWidgetState extends State<IOSCompositionWidget> {
  static const platformChannel =
      MethodChannel('com.vrin.methodchannel/cameraButton');

  dynamic nativePhoto;
  final String text = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};
    creationParams["text"] = text;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.068,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.062,
              right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.038,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      'images/help.svg',
                      height: 24,
                      width: 24,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.026,
                    ),
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      'images/timer.svg',
                      height: 24,
                      width: 24,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.028,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.262,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  'images/close.svg',
                  height: 24,
                  width: 24,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.017,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.646,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: UiKitView(
              viewType: 'NativeView',
              creationParams: creationParams,
              creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.063,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  print("pressed");
                  //TODO
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Swift Code

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
      
    let nativeViewFactory = NativeViewFactory()
    registrar(forPlugin: "Runner")!.register(nativeViewFactory, withId: "NativeView")
    
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

NativeViewFactory.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import Flutter
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class NativeViewFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory{
    
        private var nativeView: NativeView?
        private var messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
    
    func createArgsCodec() -> FlutterMessageCodec & NSObjectProtocol {
        return FlutterStandardMessageCodec.sharedInstance()
    }
    
    
    
        override init(){
        super.init()
    }
    
        init(messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger) {
                self.messenger = messenger
                super.init()
            }
    
    
        func create(withFrame frame: CGRect, viewIdentifier viewId: Int64, arguments args: Any?) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        
                self.nativeView = NativeView(
                        frame: frame,
                        viewIdentifier: viewId,
                        arguments: args,
                        binaryMessenger: messenger)
                return nativeView ?? NativeView(
                        frame: frame,
                        viewIdentifier: viewId,
                        arguments: args,
                        binaryMessenger: messenger)
            }
}



class NativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView{
    
        var likeAction: (() -> Void)?
        private var returnView: UIView?
        var previewView : UIView!
        var boxView:UIView!
        let myButton: UIButton = UIButton()
        //Camera Capture requiered properties
    
    var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
    var videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue!
    var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var imageData: Data?
    var depthData: AVDepthData?
    var depthDataMap: CVPixelBuffer?
    
    
    
    
        override init() {
                returnView = UIView()
                super.init()
            }
    
    
    
    
    
        init(
            frame: CGRect,
            viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
            arguments args: Any?,
            binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
        ) {
                returnView = UIView()
                super.init()
                // iOS views can be created here
                createNativeView(view: returnView!, args: args)
        //        ViewController()
            }
    
    
    
        func view() -> UIView {
                return returnView!
            }
    
    
    
        func receiveGyeomViewMethod(){
                print("receiveGyeomViewMethod")
            }
    
    
    
        @objc func onClickMyButton(sender: UIButton){
                print("button pressed")
            }
    
    
    
    
        func createNativeView(view _view: UIView, args: Any?){
                _view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        
        
                previewView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -150, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
                previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
                view().addSubview(previewView)
        
                self.setupAVCapture()
        
            }
    
}



extension NativeView:  AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{
    
         func setupAVCapture(){
                 session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
                let device = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices
                        print(device)
                        captureDevice = device.first
                 do {
                         let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
                         session.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
                         photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            
                         //let pixelFormatType = "kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32"
            
             //            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]
            
             //                )], completionHandler: nil)
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.hevc])], completionHandler: nil)
            
            
            
                         //captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
                         if session.canAddOutput(photoOutput!) {
                                 session.addOutput(photoOutput!)
                                 photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
                             }
                     } catch {
                             print(error)
                         }
                beginSession()
            }
    
    
        func beginSession(){
                var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        
                do {
                        deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
                        guard deviceInput != nil else {
                                print("error: cant get deviceInput")
                                return
                            }
            
                        if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
                
                                self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
                
                            }
            
                        videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
                        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
                        videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
                        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)
            
            
                        if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
                                session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
                            }
                        videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.isEnabled = true
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            
                        let rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer
                        rootLayer.masksToBounds=true
                        previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
                        rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
                        session.startRunning()
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                            deviceInput = nil
                            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
            }
    
        // clean up AVCapture
    
        func stopCamera(){
                session.stopRunning()
            }
}
```

I'm making my custom camera and I need to take picture when flutter button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a [Flutter Plugin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/write-flutter-plugin) for this feature.

To call Swift from Flutter you can use [MethodChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html).

To send result from Swift to Flutter you can [EventChanel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html)

Comment: I'm using hosting view right now but
Thx :) I'll try to make a Flutter Plugin after I finish my work :) Thx for the suggestion.